# import MetaTrader5 no module found

Tags: python, pip, metatrader5

Hi i am trying to build a trading algorithm using metatrader5 library but each time i try `pip install metatrader5` i get the following error

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement metatrader5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for metatrader5
```

i am running windows 10 as os and python 3.12
it does work on my laptop that runs windows 11 and a python version of 3.8.2 altough i have tried on this computer with python 3.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/MetaTrader5/), MetaTrader5 currently supports Python 3.6 - 3.11. To resolve your issue, you may want to downgrade to a supported version. You can either use [virtual environments](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) as this helps you to set up project-specific Python versions (as well as libraries) or you may want to uninstall the unsupported Python version and re-install any of Python versions 3.6 - 3.11. You can then install the MetaTrader 5 module from the command line using `pip install MetaTrader5` or `python -m pip install MetaTrader5`.